# How to update Django url (to include data/param) after POST

Tags: python, django

I have a search form (place names) on my home page with an auto-complete dropdown on the search input field.  When the user presses enter after selecting an item in the search box the form does  a post.
When the results return I still have the same url (https://mywebsite.com).
How do I get the selected search entry (a location name) to appear in the url so users can book mark it for later use?  eg https://mywebsite.com/mylocation

I have got the GET code working to get the location in the url - just don't know how to update the url to add the location string after the search form post.

I am new to Django so really winging it.  Have searched but found no discussion on this even in the Django docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search in one function and redirect to other.

Sample Code

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name='home'),
    path('<location>', views.homesearch, name='homesearch'),
]
```

In views.py

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        location = request.POST.get('location')
        print(location)

        if location:
            return redirect(reverse('homesearch', kwargs={'location':location}))

    return render(request, "todo/home.html")
def homesearch(request, location):

    context = {'location':location}

    return render(request, "todo/home.html", context)
```

Comment: Great - thanks Vinita for pointing me in the right direction - much appreciated.  Had to make the second path reference views.home to get it to work as I want.